# UITableView setContentOffset: called from main loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, uikeyboard

I have a `UITableView` with a variable size `UITextView` and when the user is about to enter text I move the text field up so it is visible above the keyboard. All is good. But when I adjust the `contentOffset` while the user is typing it works fine too, but a moment later the table view automatically scrolls back to the top, hiding the text view behind the keyboard. As it turns out, `setContentOffset` is for some reason called from the main loop with the initial value again. This is really ruining my day, it works all fine and then the system seems to decide to mess up my work again deliberately.

Why is this so? How can I prevent this?

Here is a screenshot of the stack trace:

[image: stack trace screenshot]

Comment: post the code what u have implemented

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you might want to take a look at [this code](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Comment: No, U wrong about " As it turns out, setContentOffset is for some reason called from the main loop with the initial value again". Simply your scrollview has contentSizeHeight. It was computed to contain all the content that scrollview has. When user activates UItextField, it get focus and keyboard appears and you set contentOffset, BUT contentSize remains the same. When you set offset it doesn't add for you a extra height. Solution:(after keyboard appears -change contentSize for ScrollView by adding keyboardHeight (Simply done by handling keyboardWasShown notification)

Comment: Or find the last element on your scrollview, and change the vertical constraint to the bottom of the scrollview. It gives you the same effect. Thus , you neatly scroll the selected field to user and he could change the position anytime he wants without strange twitching of the scrollview. When user finishes editing - you revert the contentSize (Height) to its original state. (Or directly set the new height or by modifying constraint constant and wrapping it into animation block)

Comment: Code would be helpful. But are you sure you are not reloading the `UITableView` I am guessing this since as you said the textview is variable size. So perhaps when to adjust to the changing size as text gets added you could be reloading.

Comment: @David: Thank you very much, it helped a lot except that I had to adjust the contentInset of the table, not the contentSize.

Comment: @uchiha: I used beginUpdates and endUpdates on the table instead of reloadData to update the cell height while avoiding to to lose the focus and to hide the keyboard. Maybe this was a part of the problem but unavoidable, I think.